# Vino without encryption: how dangerous is it?

Tags: ssh, lubuntu, encryption, vnc

I finally managed to set up a VNC remote connection between my laptop (with client VNC Viewer) and a desktop running Lubuntu (with server Vino; release details: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS). However, in order to do so I had to set encryption to false (I've seen this issue has been discussed many times here).

I simply would like to understand how dangerous this is: I plan to access only from my LAN and I've protected the VNC with a password. However an alert message is warning me about possible dangers every time that I turn the connection on, and I would like to know more about it.

I've read somewhere that a possible solution is to use a SSH tunnel (but do not know what it is, nor if it is useful in my situation).

Comment: Your release details are?

Comment: @guiverc Added release details - Ubuntu 16.04 (had not written them before because I thought it was a somehow general question, but I understand this pieces of info have to be there).

Comment: FYI: Lubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (https://lubuntu.me/xenial-5-released/ http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` or your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Lubuntu for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks.

Comment: Only 'main' repository packages receive back-ported security fixes now (for 16.04), so be aware a lot of your system could contain un-patched/unsupported software; do you check/audit?

Comment: @guiverc Thank you for your comments. I do not think I am aware of the risks, and indeed this is what I would like to ask here. I am using Lubuntu mostly for compatibility, I have an old Pentium 4 CPU 3GHz, 32 bit and I have picked up that distro because it is still supporting 32bit. I have no sensible data on that desktop, and I am using it (remotely) only to build Linux from scratch. What do you suggest to do?

Comment: I tested Lubuntu 18.04 LTS, 18.10 & 19.04 using a pentium 4 box, however with both 18.10 & 19.04 being EOL too, I'd opt for 18.04 myself, as it has three years of supported life (5 applies to main Ubunu with GNOME or no-desktop (server). Yes part of your 16.04 system will still be supported (the parts used by server/desktop (ie. Unity 7 default desktop), and you can use `ubuntu-support-status` to access for your own installed system the risks of unsupported packages.. If you're unsure of risks, or incapable of accessing for your circumstances, I'd opt for supported software only (to be safe).

Comment: @guiverc Done, thanks. I've updated all packages and upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Running `ubuntu-support-status` I get that more than 95% packages are still supported (and will be at least until April 2023, some of them only 2021). Thanks for letting me know this. Apparently, VNC is still working properly. Now how dangerous is it to use Vino without encryption? Thanks again.